# Is it possible to create native code with garbage collection?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Is it possible to write C++/CLI code with usage of garbage collection, which will compile to native machine code (ahead of time, not JIT)?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for? When talking C++/CLI, the opposite of "native" is "managed". Are you looking for a way to compile managed C++/CLI directly to x86, instead of IL? Or are you looking for a garbage collector that can operate on unmanaged C++ objects?

Comment: @David Yaw, C++/CLI allows to compile your source code either to native or MSIL... I'm just not sure if it's possible to allocate and access managed CLR objects in the case when code is compiled to native.

Comment: "Ahead of time" vs JIT means [NGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx), which creates processor-specfic code that runs within the CLR. (Also, see this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/).) But I suspect that's not what you are after.

Comment: @Tom Blodget, not really. C++/CLI allows to create native code ahead of time without NGEN.

Comment: Yes, a C++/CLI source file can have managed and/or unmanaged code. Unmanaged code compiles directly to x86/x86-64 instructions and uses the standard C/C++ runtime libraries. Managed code "compiles to MSIL" and uses the BCL, other .NET assemblies and/or the CLR-implementation of the C/C++ runtime libraries. But you referred to garbage collection so I assumed you meant managed code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: No (but see below)

In long:

If you use C++/CLI you automatically use IL-Code, which can be very easily decompiled with [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or other tools. But you have GC ;)

If you only want to have some parts of your C++/CLI project to be native, then you can disable the "/clr" option for this files (or better: only enable the /clr option for files which really needs .net support!). Nut in the native parts you do not have GC ;(

Alternatively you can also mark special parts of your code with [pragma managed/unmanaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adb9zxe.aspx)

```
#pragma managed
#pragma unmanaged
```

NGEN create a pre-compiled image of the assembly, but does not hide the .net code; so this is only usefull yif you have startup timing problems with your assembly. It normally makes only sence if you have UI applications. Also a side-effect is that ngened assenblies are sometimes slower than jitted assemblies. So I never use ngen...

**BUT:**

But MS now has seen that this has several problems. MS is doing some kind of improvements in this scenario. Currently only for Store-Apps but I think this will also improved to work for "normal" .NET applications. 
**That means**: You can write .NET application **with full GC support** AND these application will **compiled into NATIVE code**, without using the IL data. Only for special situations you need to IL data (like XmlSerializer).

For more infos see: 
**[Microsoft .NET Native](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/dotnetnative)**

Comment: Not completely. It's possible to reference GC objects from native code using the gcroot class.

Comment: If you mean "native" as "without MSIL", then this is wrong. You can only use a gcroot inside a "unmanaged class which is compiled with /clr"! Of course, you can pin an object and pass the pinned handle in a native function. But a native function can nothing do with this number...

Comment: Does this mean that the "unmanaged class which is compiled with /clr" will have all its methods compiled into MSIL? I can't find any its methods with Reflector.

Comment: Yes, exactly that means... the methods are in an anonymous namespace or in some kind of mystic namespace... please use ILDASM to see the MSIL code for the "unmanaged functions"...